# Ошибка undefined is not an object (evaluating) в скрипте коллажа

Tags: javascript

Прошу помочь разобраться в ошибке, которая возникает при работе скрипта фото коллажа, описанного на хабре (https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/78613/)

```
var collage = document.getElementById('collage');
var images = collage.getElementsByTagName('img');
//Маленький набор опций: averageRowHeight - примерная высота строки; gap - отступы между картинками;
var options = {averageRowHeight: 255, gap: 3};
var widths = [], rows = [], rowNumber = 0, index = 0, k = 0;
//Записываем в массив ширину каждой картинки при одинаковой высоте
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    widths.push(Math.round(images[i].width / images[i].height * options.averageRowHeight));
}
//Функция суммы элементов массива
Array.prototype.sum = function(){
    return this.reduce( function(prev,current){ return  +current + prev; }, 0);
}
//Разбиение оизображений на строки обичным деление общей ширины всех картинок на ширину контейнера
while(rowNumber < Math.ceil(widths.sum() / collage.clientWidth)){
    rows[rowNumber] = [];
    //Как только общая ширина картинок превысила ширину контейнера переходим на следующую строку
    while(index < widths.length && rows[rowNumber].sum()+(rows[rowNumber].length * options.gap) < collage.clientWidth + options.gap){
        rows[rowNumber].push(widths[index]);
        index++;
        //Если на последнюю строку осталось одно изображение, то дописываем его в "предпоследнюю"
        if(index == widths.length - 1){
            rows[rowNumber].push(widths[index]);
            rowNumber++;
            break;
        }
    }
    rowNumber++;
}
index = 0;
//Непосредственно изменение масштаба картинок (пропорционально, без обрезания изображений)
console.log(rows);
console.log(rows.length);
for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < rows[i].length; j++){
        // Если ширина строки больше/меньше ширины контейнера - соответственно
        // уменьшаем/увеличиваем до ширины контейнера с учетем отступов между картинками
        k = (collage.clientWidth - ((rows[i].length - 1) * options.gap)) / rows[i].sum();
        images[index].style.width = rows[i][j] * k  + 'px';
        images[index].style.height = k * options.averageRowHeight + 'px';
        if(j < rows[i].length - 1) images[index].style.marginRight = options.gap + 'px';
        if(i < rows.length - 1) images[index].style.marginBottom = options.gap + 'px';
        index++;
    }
}
```

В браузере Safari под mac (возможно и в каких-то других) возникает ошибка 
`undefined is not an object (evaluating 'rows[i].length')` на стоке 41

Из за неё Safari блокирует загрузку всей станицы и выполнение других скриптов на ней.

Лог консоли:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML:

```
    <div id="collage" class="clear">
        <a href="/raspoznavaniye-gribov/16290/668ee69f0ad038bbecd791d4c66f0459.jpg" title="480px x 640px" data-gallery="">
    <img src="/raspoznavaniye-gribov/16290/668ee69f0ad038bbecd791d4c66f0459.jpg" width="480" height="640">
        </a>

        <a href="/raspoznavaniye-gribov/16290/89c9f637dfe608915c0b40fe0b022246.jpg" title="640px x 480px" data-gallery="">
    <img src="/raspoznavaniye-gribov/16290/89c9f637dfe608915c0b40fe0b022246.jpg" width="640" height="480">
        </a>

        <a href="/raspoznavaniye-gribov/16290/e2da464b450dd4942d15df4d6d5dc0b2.jpg" title="640px x 480px" data-gallery="">
    <img src="/raspoznavaniye-gribov/16290/e2da464b450dd4942d15df4d6d5dc0b2.jpg" width="640" height="480">
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: у Вас в цикле `while` пропущено присвоение некоторых елементов массива `rows` из-за ошибок в логике вызовов `rowNumber++;` .

Comment: В отладчике погонять не пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал, похоже safari не нравится что там массив в массиве

Comment: добавьте в вопрос содержимое консоли после вызова `console.log(rows);` перед двойным `for`

Comment: какая строка из приведенных в вопросе имеет номер 36?

Comment: Grundy , `for(var j = 0; j < rows[i].length; j++){`

Comment: ну что, еще вопросы есть? где элемент с индексом 1?

Answer (score 1):

У Вас в цикле `while` пропущено присвоение некоторых елементов массива `rows` из-за ошибок в логике вызовов `rowNumber++;`.

А именно - пропущено присвоение элемента с индексом 1.

Бросается в глаза: `rowNumber++;` во внутреннем и внешнем циклах `while` - что вызывает перескакивание индекса `rowNumber` через одно значение в случае выполнения внутреннего `if`.

На всякий случай: команда `break;` в Вашем коде прерывает только один цикл - тот, в котором она непосредственно находится.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как поправить. Код не мой.

Comment: @ЛеонидОзёрный Э-э-э, нет. Пошаговая отладка - личное дело каждого. Бросается в глаза: `rowNumber++;` во внутреннем и внешнем циклах `while` - что вызывает перескакивание индекса `rowNumber` через одно значение в случае выполнения внутреннего `if`.

Comment: @Igor, а если у break стоит метка, то и несколько циклов может прервать

Comment: @Igor а разве вот это `var widths = [], rows = [], rowNumber = 0, index = 0, k = 0;` не присвоение элемента?

Comment: @ЛеонидОзёрный нет, `rows = [],` это создание массива. Речь идет о строке `rows[rowNumber] = [];`.

Answer (score -1):

Возможно, на странице отсутствует `div` с `id="collage"`

Comment: нет, он там есть

Comment: html-листинг увидеть было бы неплохо

Comment: добавил html код в вопрос